# Page height in safari is WRONG, lot of empty space

Tags: html, css, safari

http://teothemes.com/wp

I have some elements with height: 100%, but in safari the height of the page goes way after the content, it adds lots of empty lines without any content.

I tried removing the height: 100%, tried with height: auto but without success.

If anyone has any clue, I really appreciate it!

Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with height 100%? And please be more specific, which elements are you talking about? Please provide code example and explain the problem, and ask a question.

Comment: I can't see any difference between Safari, Chrome y FF, are you using the lastest version of each one?

Comment: There is a lot of empty space at the end of the page in latest safari on OS X

Comment: Just checked in Safari on MacBook Pro and like Luis said, I can't see any difference either!

Comment: I fixed it, the .homelava element had a top: 5000px which was causing the issue :)

Comment: hm... the only thing I could think of is a different resolution that could cause that problem... do you have to scroll or is the content on the side without you having to scroll?